# Safely assign values from one object to another in a for loop

Tags: typescript

### Description

I have two types which are similar but not identical

```js
type A = {
  a?: number
  b?: string
  c?: boolean
}

type B = {
  a?: number
  b?: string
  c?: string
}
```

I want to write an adapter function `f()` that converts from type A to B. Importantly, **only properties populated in A should populate B**.

```js
function f(a: A): B
```

This should be as simple as a for loop:

```js
function f(a: A): B {
  const b: B = {}
  for (const key of Object.keys(a) as Array<keyof A>) {
    if (key === 'c') {
      b.c = String(a[key])
    } else {
      b[key] = a[key] // ❌ Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    }
  }
  return b
}
```

The above code works and, in my mind, is type safe. I can see why typescript doesn't really understand why it's type safe but it should? How do I make it understand the types correctly?

---

### What I've tried

1. Grouping if's by type of value:

```js
function g(a: A): B {
  const b: B = {}
  for (const key of Object.keys(a) as Array<keyof A>) {
    if (key === 'c') {
      b.c = String(a[key])
    } else if (key === 'a') {
      // Handle numbers
      b[key] = a[key]
    } else {
      // Handle strings
      b[key] = a[key]
    }
  }
  return b
}
```

I don't like the above solution because many branches will have duplicate code. The more types of value, the more duplicate code. The more keys the harder it is to read. Each time a key is added the function will have to be updated, violating [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

2. Spreading

This is performance critical code and I have some concerns about creating many objects just to immediately spread them into another object. This should be as simple as setting a key?

There must be a simpler way of doing all this?

Answer (score 0):

TSC doesnt know that any remaining keys are guaranteed to be the same value. There is no "link" between the remaining properties of A and B, after plucking out C.

So either explicitly build the new B object by specifying its properties, or build up the type layer so that they inherit each other.

Just help TSC pluck apart the shared properties, and explicitly pluck out the shared properties rather than use an imperative iterator

[explicit approach:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQwE4QCYAUkHswGcoC8UA3gFBQVQID8AXFAHYCuAtgEYRIDc5lbdUXMCQBLBgHMeAX1KlQkKAEFCsRCgzY8UAGQleAYwFssWADYQEDUjLnhoAIRXxkaTDny6yFQ-SGiJ1rIAZkwM%20sAiWAxQQQAUCPSKAJT0jl5Q%20lFCJBn0CADCADRQAHRluGpoUFIqCDwGWcBQbKkq6ZS5sMJi4vH5SYW8HWUlFS6ovFL1FCjATEjRbNJAA)

```
type A = {
  a?: number;
  b?: string;
  c?: boolean
}

type B = {
  a?: number;
  b?: string;
  c?: string
}

function f(a: A): B {
  const b: B = {
      a: a.a,
      b: a.b,
      c: String(a.c),
  };

  return b;
}
```

[inheritance:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGB%20AXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcaUpuUAzsBQJb4DmN6Axg6QHsBAGwgZ8KAL4oUoSFABCCZLWx4iZStzoNmbTtr5497DlJkAzQvh7BWA-FAsAKDHhgBKPEtS8HzOm9lX3RQt0wAOgwAGlpQwMjSWPjePABlFlNXCJ4PZKhJGloKCGBCCkdSGmkUIA)

```
type SharedProps = {
    a?: number;
    b?: string;
}

type A = SharedProps & {
  c?: boolean
}

type B = SharedProps & {
  c?: string
}

function f(a: A): B {
  const { c: aC, ...shared } = a;

  const b: B = {
      c: String(aC),
      ...shared
  };

  return b;
}
```

Comment: The primary issue with both of these solutions is they don't account for the important limitation in bold **"only properties populated in A should populate B."** I did think of these two solutions and in most scenarios they are neat solutions, thanks!